# csv-xls python error "Should Return Strings, Not Bytes"

Tags: excel, csv, python-3.x, xls

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Office\Documents\Development\CSV-XLS.py", line 12, in 
    for rowi, row in enumerate(g):
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I read something here about  text-mode files but couldn't make heads or tails of it.
Any help is much appreciated!

```
import sys, csv, xlwt

files = [r'C:\Users\Office\Downloads\TEST.csv']

for i in files:
 f = open(i, 'rb')
   g = csv.reader((f), delimiter=";")
   workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
   sheet = xlwt.Workbook()
   sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

    for rowi, row in enumerate(g):
    for coli, value in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(rowi, coli, value)
    workbook.save(i + ".xls")
```